# I try to rotat without lib but it make black points in picture

Tags: java, arrays, math, image-processing, imageicon

I am trying to rotate image without standard method , making color array and manipulate it, but when I invoke the, rotation I get black points (look the picture)

[image]

Here is my code, colScaled is the picture I am trying to convert to an array:

```
public void arrays() {
    colScaled = zoom2();
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    angel = Integer.parseInt(this.mn.jTextField1.getText());
    float degree = (float) Math.toRadians(angel);
    float cos = (float) Math.cos(degree);
    float sin = (float) Math.sin(degree);
    int W = Math.round(colScaled[0].length * Math.abs(sin) + colScaled.length * Math.abs(cos));
    int H = Math.round(colScaled[0].length * Math.abs(cos) + colScaled.length * Math.abs(sin));
    int x;
    int y;
    int xn = (int) W / 2;
    int yn = (int) H / 2;
    int hw = (int) colScaled.length / 2;
    int hh = (int) colScaled[0].length / 2;
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(W + 1, H + 1, im.getType());
    for (i = 0; i < colScaled.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < colScaled[0].length; j++) {
            x = Math.round((i - hw) * cos - (j - hh) * sin + xn);
            y = Math.round((i - hw) * sin + (j - hh) * cos + yn);
            image.setRGB(x, y, colScaled[i][j]);
        }
    }
    ImageIcon ico = new ImageIcon(image);
    this.mn.jLabel1.setIcon(ico);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java rotation of pixel array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739809/java-rotation-of-pixel-array)

Comment: "black points" where?? in the image or surrounding the image?

Comment: In the image  , Surrounding is not matter

Comment: I will be really Thanckfull if you can help me

Answer (score 0):

Notice this block in your code :-

```
for (i = 0; i < colScaled.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < colScaled[0].length; j++) {
        x = Math.round((i - hw) * cos - (j - hh) * sin + xn);
        y = Math.round((i - hw) * sin + (j - hh) * cos + yn);
        image.setRGB(x, y, colScaled[i][j]);
    }
}
```

The `x` and `y` is pixel coordinate in **source** image (`colScaled`).
The objective of this code is to fill all pixels in **destination** image (`image`).

In your loop, there is no guarantee that all pixels in the destination image will be filled, even it is in the rectangle zone.

[image]

The above image depict the problem.
See?  It is possible that the red pixel in the **destination** image will not be written.

The correct solution is to iterating pixel in **destination** image, then find a corresponding pixel in **source** image later.

**Edit:** After posting, I just saw the Spektre's comment.
 I agree, it seems to be a duplicated question.  The word "pixel array" made me thing it is not.